# error: package com.bumptech.glide.request.animation does not exist

Tags: android, android-glide

I added package in app gradle following package:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

But while run getting below error:

error: package com.bumptech.glide.request.animation does not exist

Anyone faced like this?

Comment: have you added `mavenCentral()`

Comment: @NileshRathod yes

Comment: Share your code and Whole Crash log with question

Comment: No crash while just run project getting error: package com.bumptech.glide.request.animation does not exist

Comment: post your gradle now please

Comment: E:\android\tripplanapp\app\src\main\java\com\tripplanapp\tripline\adapters\recyclerview\posts\GalleryAdapter.java:28: error: package com.bumptech.glide.request.animation does not exist
import com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.GlideAnimation;

Comment: Have you tried to sync gradle and import GlideAnimation class to your code?

Comment: @sontruongit yes

Comment: Can you add your gradle file and the code where you call Glide API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GladeAnimation has been replaced by Transition, so now instead of

```
onResourceReady(GlideDrawable drawable, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> anim)
```

you should use

```
onResourceReady(Drawable drawable, Transition<? super Drawable> transition);
```

You should check all the different migration changes from the [official site](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**for version 3 you used to like this:**

```
   private void setFeedImage(Uri imageUrl,File file) {
        BitmapImageViewTarget target = new BitmapImageViewTarget(feedImage) {

     @Override
            public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap bitmap,GlideAnimation anim) {
                super.onResourceReady(bitmap,anim);
                feedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0,stream);
                byte[] bitmapBytes = stream.toByteArray();

                ParseFile image = new ParseFile("postImage",bitmapBytes);
                post.setPostImage(image);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFailed(Exception e,Drawable errorDrawable) {
                super.onLoadFailed(e,errorDrawable);
                feedImage.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
                super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                feedImage.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            }
```

**but for version 4 you should use like this instead of top code :**

```
  private void setFeedImage(Uri imageUrl,File file) {
            BitmapImageViewTarget target = new BitmapImageViewTarget(feedImage) {

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    super.onResourceReady(resource, transition);

                    feedImage.setImageBitmap(resource);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0,stream);
                    byte[] bitmapBytes = stream.toByteArray();

                    ParseFile image = new ParseFile("postImage",bitmapBytes);
                    post.setPostImage(image);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
                    feedImage.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadStarted(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                    super.onLoadStarted(placeholder);
                    feedImage.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle with:

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.+'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'

Comment: Glide.with(ctx).load(url)
                 ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found